# How to select ListBox items multiple times using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a windows form with 2 comboboxes and a list box. Each one displaying items dependent on what is selected in each.

For the listbox, multiselect is enabled and working, but i want to be able to allow the selection of the items in the listbox to be selected more than once. Allowing the user to select the same item/items multiple times, if that makes sense.

Im using VS2015

**Here is my current code:**

```
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Configuration
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

   Public Class MainHome

Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\\Galactic\TSC_TIME_MATRIX$\DEV\TMX.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
'Dim constr As String
Dim querystring As String


' "Please Select" doesn't work well in the ListBox, I added it as an option
Private Shared Function GetData(ByVal sql As String, insertPleaseSelect As Boolean) As DataTable
    Dim constr As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\\Galactic\TSC_TIME_MATRIX$\DEV\TMX.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
            sda.Fill(dt)
            If insertPleaseSelect Then
                Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                row(0) = 1
                row(1) = "Please Select"
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)
            End If
            Return dt
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

Private Sub MainHome_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT  [SizeId], [SizeName] FROM [Size]", True)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "SizeName"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "SizeId"
    ComboBox2.Enabled = False
    ListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple ' allow multi-select
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    ComboBox2.DataSource = Nothing
    ComboBox2.Enabled = False
    If ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() <> "0" Then
        Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT [DetailLevelId], [DetailLevelName] FROM [DetailLevel] WHERE [SizeId] = {0}", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
        ComboBox2.DataSource = GetData(sql, True)
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "DetailLevelName"
        ComboBox2.ValueMember = "DetailLevelId"
        ComboBox2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectionChangeCommitted
    ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
    ListBox1.Enabled = False
    If ComboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() <> "0" Then
        Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT [OperationsId], [OperationsName], [OperationsTime] FROM [Operations] WHERE [DetailLevelId] = {0}", ComboBox2.SelectedValue)
        ListBox1.DataSource = GetData(sql, False)
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "OperationsName" ' changed this from ValueMember to DisplayMember
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "OperationsTime"
        ListBox1.Enabled = True
        ListBox1.ClearSelected() ' Every time the ListBox is populated, clear it
    End If
End Sub

' Added this handler to respond to user input, not programmatic selection changes
Private Sub ListBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.Click
    ' Here is the sum

    'TotalMinutes
    Dim TotalMinutes = ListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of DataRowView).Sum(Function(o) CType(o("OperationsTime"), Double))
    lbTotalMins.Text = TotalMinutes


    'Total Hours
    Dim TotalHours = ListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of DataRowView).Sum(Function(o) CType(o("OperationsTime"), Double)) / 60.0
    lbTotalHours.Text = Format(TotalHours, "0.00")

    'Total Days
    Dim TotalDays = ListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of DataRowView).Sum(Function(o) CType(o("OperationsTime"), Double)) / 1440.0
    lbTotalDays.Text = Format(TotalDays, "0.0")


    'Oven TIme
    Dim CureOvenSum = ListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of DataRowView).Where(Function(o) o("OperationsName").ToString() = "CURE/OVEN").Sum(Function(o) CType(o("OperationsTime"), Double)) / 60

    Dim postCureOvenSum = ListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of DataRowView).Where(Function(o) o("OperationsName").ToString() = "POST CURE/OVEN").Sum(Function(o) CType(o("OperationsTime"), Double)) / 60
    lbTotalOven.Text = Format(postCureOvenSum + CureOvenSum, "0.00")

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Using sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)

    ' Dim constr As String
    ' Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\hartj\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TIMEMATRIX2.0\TIMEMATRIX2.0\TMX.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    Try
        con.Open()

        querystring = "INSERT INTO ArchiveData(DATE,PART_NUMBER,JOB_NUMBER,REV,IMS_DATE,ASSEMBLY_SIZE,DETAIL_LEVEL,OPERATIONS,USER_NAME,TOTAL_TIME,TOTAL_HOURS,TOTAL_DAYS,TOTAL_OVEN,NOTES)VALUES(' " & MainStart.tbDateToday.Text & " ',' " & tbPartNum.Text & " ',' " & tbJobNum.Text & " ',' " & tbRev.Text & " ',' " & tbIMS.Text & " ',' " & ComboBox1.Text & " ',' " & ComboBox2.Text & " ',' " & ListBox1.Text & " ',' " & MainStart.tbUserName.Text & " ',' " & lbTotalMins.Text & " ',' " & lbTotalHours.Text & " ',' " & lbTotalDays.Text & " ',' " & lbTotalOven.Text & " ',' " & rtbNOTES.Text & " ')"

        Dim Comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(querystring, con)

        Comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Data Succesfully Saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "add")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        con.Close()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense.  You want a user to select an already highlighted item in the ListBox?

Comment: Never concat strings+to+male+SQL + " " + queries.  Always use SQL parameters.  Set aside 30 mins to learn about them

Comment: Yes essentially. If they want to select any item already selected, again.

Comment: Put a button on the form and perform whatever action you want with the highlighted items.  No user is going to understand that they need to keep highlighting an already highlighted item.

Comment: why would you want them to select the same thing twice? What does that achieve? As others have said, it's a completely unconventional UX and you're going to have trouble getting users to understand it. Also, how would you indicate to them how many times they've selected it? WinForms doesn't provide a way to do this for a reason - it's not logical.

Comment: The listbox shows a list of operations for a specific job. When they select the operations required for the job, the estimated time for each operation is displayed in a label. The problem i need to solve is that some jobs require multiple instances of the same operation. So if they could click on them mor then once or select them more than once they would be able to see the time counter increase. Ive accomplished this in excel vba but the same function doesnt work in winforms.

Comment: Any other potential ideas or suggestions?